# How to select all Mondays (or any day combo like MTW, WTTh) between two given dates in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, date

What I see over the internet is just counting how many days occur whenever you input the day of the week you need. Like between May 1 to May 31, how many mondays are there in it. What I need is to display the dates where it is monday between two given dates. I don't have any code for this now since I don't really know where to start as I've scanned already the MySQL docu but I haven't seen anything useful besides

```
WEEKDAY('1998-02-03 22:23:00')
```

or

```
DAYOFWEEK('1998-02-03')
```

which shows the day index of a certain date. (but this time, of course, I don't know which dates fall on Mondays., i need the reverse thing)

I need is when I need mondays and tuesdays in february, it will return the following:

2015-02-02
2015-02-03
2015-02-09
2015-02-10
2015-02-16
2015-02-17
2015-02-23
2015-02-24

I dont have any code to display since my progresses in mysql on our proj isn't directly related to this one I'm needing. This is another independent mysql query of our proj I'm trying to get done..

Comment: Can the answer to this question use a new table in your database?

Comment: it's okay as long as the job gets done

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/510209/470530), I modified the query slightly to get

```
select adddate('2015-02-01', numlist.id) as `my_date`, 
       weekday(adddate('2015-02-01', numlist.id)) as day_no,
       dayname(adddate('2015-02-01', numlist.id)) as `day_name` 
from
(SELECT n1.i + n10.i*10 + n100.i*100 AS id
   FROM num n1 cross join num as n10 cross join num as n100) as numlist
where adddate('2015-02-01', numlist.id) <= '2015-02-28'
and dayname(adddate('2015-02-01', numlist.id)) in( 'Monday', 'Tuesday');
```

which gives

```
+------------+--------+----------+
| my_date    | day_no | day_name |
+------------+--------+----------+
| 2015-02-02 |      0 | Monday   |
| 2015-02-03 |      1 | Tuesday  |
| 2015-02-09 |      0 | Monday   |
| 2015-02-10 |      1 | Tuesday  |
| 2015-02-16 |      0 | Monday   |
| 2015-02-17 |      1 | Tuesday  |
| 2015-02-23 |      0 | Monday   |
| 2015-02-24 |      1 | Tuesday  |
+------------+--------+----------+
8 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

or from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13814885/470530)

```
select * from 
(select adddate('1970-01-01',t4*10000 + t3*1000 + t2*100 + t1*10 + t0) selected_date from
 (select 0 t0 union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t0,
 (select 0 t1 union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t1,
 (select 0 t2 union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t2,
 (select 0 t3 union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t3,
 (select 0 t4 union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t4) v
where selected_date between '2015-02-01' and '2015-02-28'
and dayname(selected_date) in ('Monday', 'Tuesday');
```

result

```
+---------------+
| selected_date |
+---------------+
| 2015-02-02    |
| 2015-02-03    |
| 2015-02-09    |
| 2015-02-10    |
| 2015-02-16    |
| 2015-02-17    |
| 2015-02-23    |
| 2015-02-24    |
+---------------+
8 rows in set (0.23 sec)


CREATE TABLE mydate( blah date);

INSERT INTO mydate (blah)
select adddate('2015-02-01', numlist.id) as `my_date`
--       weekday(adddate('2015-02-01', numlist.id)) as day_no,
--       dayname(adddate('2015-02-01', numlist.id)) as `day_name` 
from
(SELECT n1.i + n10.i*10 + n100.i*100 AS id
   FROM num n1 cross join num as n10 cross join num as n100) as numlist
where adddate('2015-02-01', numlist.id) <= '2015-05-28'
and dayname(adddate('2015-02-01', numlist.id)) in( 'Monday', 'Tuesday');
```

(need a table num)

```
mysql> select * from mydate;
+------------+
| blah       |
+------------+
| 2015-02-02 |
| 2015-02-03 |
| 2015-02-09 |
| 2015-02-10 |
| 2015-02-16 |
| 2015-02-17 |
| 2015-02-23 |
| 2015-02-24 |
| 2015-03-02 |
```

**OR**

```
insert into mydate (blah) 
select * from 
(select adddate('1970-01-01',t4*10000 + t3*1000 + t2*100 + t1*10 + t0) selected_date from
 (select 0 t0 union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t0,
 (select 0 t1 union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t1,
 (select 0 t2 union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t2,
 (select 0 t3 union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t3,
 (select 0 t4 union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t4) v
where selected_date between '2015-02-01' and '2015-05-28'
and dayname(selected_date) in ('Monday', 'Tuesday');
```

No table necessary. Same result as above.

Comment: Thanks! the 2nd one works, kinda slow, but its okay! btw, how does the 1st solution implemented? Do I have to create a table with the 3 columns? and oh i forgot to mention that I'll be inserting these data to another table, is it enough that I will replace the insert into? or what? What I meant with select is to obtain the dates. My bad. Thank you very much for your reply. :)

Comment: The advantage of the second one is that it doesn't require an ancilliary table (num). Check my edit to my original answer.

Comment: Your last edit was my answer (http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/91143/877) to his other question from 2 hours ago. The date generation looks heavy handed (All dates since 1970-01-01 ?) I am amazed how faster to collects dates.