# How to insert the gathered dates into another table using INSERT SELECT in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, select, insert, date

```
insert into rfdate (date)
select adddate('1970-01-01',t4*10000 + t3*1000 + t2*100 + t1*10 + t0) selected_date from
(select 0 t0 union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4
union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t0,
(select 0 t1 union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4
union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t1,
(select 0 t2 union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4
union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t2,
(select 0 t3 union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4
union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t3,
(select 0 t4 union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4
union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t4
where selected_date between '2015-02-01' and '2015-02-28'
and dayname(selected_date) in ('Monday', 'Tuesday')
```

Above code doesn't work.

Code below gathers the needed date irregardless of where database you are in since it's just date. You can try it too even without using a table with the columns presented.

```
select * from 
(select adddate('1970-01-01',t4*10000 + t3*1000 + t2*100 + t1*10 + t0) selected_date from
(select 0 t0 union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4
union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t0,
(select 0 t1 union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4
union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t1,
(select 0 t2 union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4
union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t2,
(select 0 t3 union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4
union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t3,
(select 0 t4 union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4
union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t4) v
where selected_date between '2015-02-01' and '2015-02-28'
and dayname(selected_date) in ('Monday', 'Tuesday');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## PROPOSED QUERY

```
insert into rfdate (date)
select selected_date from
(
    select adddate('1970-01-01',t4*10000 + t3*1000 + t2*100 + t1*10 + t0) selected_date
    from
        (select 0 t0 union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4
        union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t0,
        (select 0 t1 union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4
        union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t1,
        (select 0 t2 union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4
        union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t2,
        (select 0 t3 union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4
        union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t3,
        (select 0 t4 union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4
        union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t4
) A where selected_date between '2015-02-01' and '2015-02-28'
and dayname(selected_date) in ('Monday', 'Tuesday');
```

## PROOF THAT IT WORKS

```
mysql> DROP DATABASE jeffvalerio;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.02 sec)

mysql> CREATE DATABASE jeffvalerio;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> USE jeffvalerio
Database changed
mysql> CREATE TABLE rfdate
    -> (
    ->     id int not null auto_increment,
    ->     date date,
    ->     PRIMARY KEY (id)
    -> );
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.05 sec)

mysql> insert into rfdate (date)
    -> select selected_date from
    -> (
    ->     select adddate('1970-01-01',t4*10000 + t3*1000 + t2*100 + t1*10 + t0) selected_date
    ->     from
    ->         (select 0 t0 union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4
    ->         union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t0,
    ->         (select 0 t1 union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4
    ->         union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t1,
    ->         (select 0 t2 union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4
    ->         union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t2,
    ->         (select 0 t3 union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4
    ->         union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t3,
    ->         (select 0 t4 union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4
    ->         union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t4
    -> ) A where selected_date between '2015-02-01' and '2015-02-28'
    -> and dayname(selected_date) in ('Monday', 'Tuesday');
Query OK, 8 rows affected (0.09 sec)
Records: 8  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0
```

Here is the table's contents

```
mysql> select * from rfdate;
+----+------------+
| id | date       |
+----+------------+
|  1 | 2015-02-02 |
|  2 | 2015-02-03 |
|  3 | 2015-02-09 |
|  4 | 2015-02-10 |
|  5 | 2015-02-16 |
|  6 | 2015-02-17 |
|  7 | 2015-02-23 |
|  8 | 2015-02-24 |
+----+------------+
8 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

## GIVE IT A TRY !!!

Comment: "#1054 - Unknown column 'selected_date' in 'where clause' " That's the output error. :(

Comment: Just fixed it...